# A* Search with heuristics, I am trying to determine the heuristics

Tags: math, graph, computer-science, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a search graph v1-v30, V=vertex(node), I use time in minutes between the vertex on a road network traveling salesman problem.

how do I determine the heuristics between these vertices?

I have already draft up a heuristics table with assumptions (Educated Guesses) of the time it would take between the nodes.

For example: from v1-v2 i have 20 minutes obtain from google map with the location i am using. I then used a heuristics h(n) value of 30minutes based off pure observation and educated guess.

Am I on the right path by assuming the heuristics the way I did?

Also how does A* handle dead ends?

Comment: please format your question

Comment: just did, is it ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A* handles dead ends just fine. I don't think you should use that strategy for your heuristic though. If you are wrong (if for some reason you overestimate the time it will take), your A* is not guaranteed to find the optimal path. If you're using Google maps, you could use the straight line distance from start to finish using the lat/long values of map markers

Regarding dead ends, Since A* gives a lower priority to any states that it guesses will take a long time to complete, a state that has `current_node = v22` and `prev_node = v20` will have have a lower priority than the state that never went down that path to the dead end. In this way the A* algorithm will gracefully ignore these dead end states. So you don't really even need to worry about manually recursing back up the path yourself.

Comment: Can you explain how it handles dead ends?

Comment: The specific behaviour depends on your implementation. How are you keeping track of your visited nodes? And if you could say why you are so worried about dead ends, I might be able to give more relevant details

Comment: i am calculating all possible routes from start v1-v30: so i write down all the possible routes first i have around 10 so far. If I take one different node for example: v10-v11 instead of say v10-v14 does that account for a new route?

Comment: Do you mean you want all the possible routes from v1 to v30, or that you want to precompute the fastest route from all possible starts and ends ie: v1->v2, v1->v3, .... v1->v30, v2->v1, .... v30->v29. If it's the former, then you probably don't want A*. If it's the latter, then just worry about getting A* working for a single route, then write a loop that runs it for all possibilities. I'll try and update my answer to explain dead ends more, but I'm still not 100% sure what you are worried about.

Comment: Do you mean you want all the possible routes from v1 to v30<<<THIS.                                          As it related to dead ends I have calculated them and then backtracked out of them and accounted for the time to go into the dead end and the time to exit out of it. example v20-v22 is a dead end if it takes 10 minutes to go into it then I backtrack 10 minutes also to exit.

Comment: Right. So If you do A* correctly, then it will return the same, shortest path from v1 to v30 every time, for example: v1->v2->v8->v22->v18->v30. There is no way to get it to return another possible route, especially if it's not optimal. It sounds like you probably want another algorithm; possibly  Breadth First Search, since it 'fans out' across the whole graph.

Comment: v1->v2->v8->v22->v18->v30 so what I am doing by writing down all the other routes is not correct. Since I have written down all the possible routes from v1-v30 before deciding which one is the shortest path to v30.

Comment: Yeah, there's not much point doing that. A* guarantees that the first path from v1 to v30 it finds is the optimal path. So as long as you have a working version of it, you can just run it once and get the shortest route. If you are writing them all out to test whether it's actually finding the shortest path, maybe try running it on simpler graphs where it's easy to tell what the fastest route is. That way you don't have to write them all out.

Comment: Thanks much. So just to be clear this is correct?>>>>>>>As it related to dead ends I have calculated them and then backtracked out of them and accounted for the time to go into the dead end and the time to exit out of it. example v20-v22 is a dead end if it takes 10 minutes to go into it then I backtrack 10 minutes also to exit.

Comment: I just edited my answer to explain how A* handles dead ends more

Comment: so basically, I should list all possible routes then ignoring the dead ends?     Please remember I am writing all the possible routes out.

Comment: You should ignore the dead ends, yes. But I don't really understand why you are listing all possible routes. Is it just to get an idea of which path will be the shortest?

Comment: yes, it is required for what I am doing by the lecturer.

Comment: Right, well if your lecturer said to list all paths, then I guess you have to do that, but I don't see how it will help figure out what's happening with A*. To test whether your A* works, I suggest running it on simpler graphs first, like this one: https://in.linkedin.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAobAAAAJDNlNjE2OWIyLTYyZWItNDA5NC05OWU5LTNlY2FmZGMyYjg5ZQ.png The path A* will return from A->F will only ever be A->C->E->D->F.